# How to unlock a PC when connected through Remote Desktop

Tags: windows, remote-desktop

How do I unlock a PC from another one by accessing through a Remote Desktop Connection?

I use more than one PC in Office, and all of these are in different locations. I need to be able to unlock one from another.

Comment: is it not crtl-alt-end ? Thats a guess mind

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking to login yourself, you connect and are presented with the login screen. Enter the account username and password and you're there.  If you're trying to unlock the computer for someone else, you may want to look at a VNC-type tool which will show the desktop to whoever is at the console.